# Nginx on 443, but node handling ssl certificates

Tags: node.js, ssl, nginx

We have nginx running two servers (port 80 and 443).  These `proxy_pass` our upstreams:

```
   upstream app_nodes {
       ip_hash;
       server 127.0.0.1:3000;
       server 127.0.0.1:3001;
    }

    upstream app_nodes_https {
      ip_hash;
      server 127.0.0.1:8000;
      server 127.0.0.1:8001;
    }
```

For port 80, this is fine.  However, for 443 this fails because we don't have ssl certs defined within nginx.  We need our node.js app (listening on port 8000/8001) to handle the certificates to support many domains dynamically.

Is there a way to have nginx simply proxy our upstream servers and let them handle ssl?

Thank you

EDIT:  Here's our server block for 443

```
server {
       listen 443;

       gzip on;
       gzip_types text/plain application/json application/ocet-stream;

       location / {
          proxy_pass      https://app_nodes_https;    
          add_header      X-Upstream  $upstream_addr;
          add_header      X-Real-IP $remote_addr;       
          include         /etc/nginx/proxy_params;
       }

}
```

Doing `nginx -t` actually gives the error that `https protocol requires SSL support`

Comment: Since you cannot look into the HTTP part of the traffic if nginx is not the SSL endpoint you need to use plain TCP for load balancing instead. See [nginx load balancing – tcp and udp load balancer](https://www.nginx.com/resources/admin-guide/tcp-load-balancing/).

Comment: It says that TCP is the default, presumably just `listen 443;` which we use is TCP

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to use streams:

```
stream {
        upstream https_stream {
          hash $remote_addr;
          server 127.0.0.1:8000;
          server 127.0.0.1:8001;
        }
        server {
          listen 443;
          proxy_pass https_stream;
        }
}
```

This is assuming your running your app instances on 8000/8001.